# HTML link that changes a description using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am designing a website where, on the sidebar, I have links. I need the links to be able to change the content of the site itself and not link to another page. The site is getting really large and this is my attempt to keep it small. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code for these links; I would need to change the subLink div description.

[JSFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/86dQj/)

```
<div id="sidebarLinks"><!-- USE THIS DIV SECTION FOR A LIST WITH BULLET POINTS -->
    <ul>
        <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="index.html"><strong><em>Main Page</em></strong></a></li>
        <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="construction.html#bottom">Construction</a></li>
            <ul id="subList">
                <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="#">HOME MECHANICS</a></li>
                <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="#">BUILDING CONSTRUCTION 1</a></li>
                <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="#">BUILDING CONSTRUCTION 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="drafting.html#bottom">Drafting</a></li>
        <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="electronics.html#bottom">Electronics</a></li>
        <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="graphic.html#bottom">Graphic arts </a></li>
        <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="Manufacturing.html#bottom">Manufacturing</a></li>
        <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="project.html#bottom">Project Lead the Way</a></li>
        <li style="line-height: 20px"><a href="transport.html#bottom">Transportation, Distribution, & Logistics</a></li>
        <li style="line-height: 35px"><a href="woodworking.html#bottom">Wood Working</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I didnt get it with " I need to be able to change the output on the website" and "a class description".. ?!

Comment: `I would need to change the subLink div` to what? I don't even see a "subLink div". What have you tried already?

Comment: Sorry for my poor wording on the website there is a description area that I would like to be able to change what the description is without changing the webpage

Comment: Ajax is what you are looking for I think

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right - you want to change dynamically some content after clicking on list item?

If so: there are few ways to do it

1)You can declare some div element and change its content after onclick event is triggered (you fill .html() property with JQuery or .innerHTML() with pure Javascript with string that has html definitions inside it).

2)You can use AJAX to load some html page into your prepared div.

If you want to load new pages into your page, the option 2) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the whole content is put in a div like

```
 <div id="container">
     Your content here
 </div>
```

And make your links call a function where this is called, for example

```
function changeThings(url){
    $("container").load(url,callback)
}
```

And your links would be like

```
 <a onclick='changeThings("drafting.html#bottom")' >Drafting</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same structure for all your pages then you can use the **ajax** to modify the content of your divs according to your pages from the external files.
http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/

If the structure will also change then you can develop all the pages in one page only and show and hide the respective divs on the click of your links. We call these type of websites as the single page websites.